# Should express router.get intervene page loading?

Tags: javascript, express, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angularjs-http

I have built a mean-stack application. I use `http` to communicate data between front-end and back-end. For example,

In front-end, I have

```
app.factory('ops', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var o = {};
    o.get = function (id) {
        return $http.get('/ops/' + id)
            .then(function (res) {
                return res.data
            })
    };
    return o;
}]);
```

In the back-end, in `routes/index.js`, I have

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

... ...
router.get('/ops/:op', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("/ops/:op");
    res.json(req.op);
})

module.exports = router;
```

And it is the job of `ui-router` to load a page like `https://localhost:3000/ops/59202d6a38b09685ff6b0581`:

```
.state('ops', {
    url: '/ops/{id}',
    ...
```

However, since I turned `html5Mode` to `true`, it seems that `router.get('/ops/:op', function (req, res, next) { console.log("/ops/:op"); res.json(req.op); })` **can directly** load the page `https://localhost:3000/ops/59202d6a38b09685ff6b0581`. If I comment `.state('ops' ...` and load the page, I see `/ops/:op` is displayed in the server console, and the content of the json data is shown in the browser. At the same time, in the browser console, I see

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "https://localhost:3000/ops/59202d6a38b09685ff6b0581"
```

Could anyone tell me if we should let `router.get('/ops/:op' ...` intervenue the loading of a page in this way? If not, how could we disable it?

PS: `routers/index.js` is referenced in `app.js` as follows:

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);
```